# crash passing parameter from one viewcontroller to another

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, viewcontroller

I'm trying to pass parameter from one view controller to another, but application `crashes` with exception.

My code is this:

```
SelectedItemViewController *nextView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SelectedItemViewID"];

nextView.m_selectedItemId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:777];

[self presentViewController:nextView animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

And I have the following in my stack:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setM_selectedItemId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c765d0'`

Comment: Are you sure, your view'controller identifier is `SelectedItemViewID`?

Comment: yes more than sure :) looks like issue related to navigation controller. My view embedded into navigation controller and this ID is a navigation controller id. I don't know how to pass params if there is a navigation controller also.

Answer (score 3):

In your storyboard, the view controller with identifier `SelectedItemViewID` is a navigation controller, not a `SelectedItemViewController`. So, before you set `m_selectedItemId` you should access the navigation controllers root view controller (which should be your `SelectedItemViewController`).

Comment: Wain you are right regarding view controller ID, but I'm passing navigation controller ID because my SelectedItemViewController embedded into navigation controller, and I need to redirect to it, otherwise I'm loosing navigation bar. Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: You need to get the view controller from the nav controller, like `navigationController.viewControllers[0];`

Answer (score 2):

I found solution here: [instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier and pass data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832706/instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier-and-pass-data)

What should be done in case if you want to pass parameter to view controller via navigation controller:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SelectedItemViewID"];

SelectedItemViewController *nextView = navigationController.viewControllers[0];

nextView.m_selectedItemId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:777];

[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select the view controller in your storyboard, is the class set to `SelectedItemViewController`?

Obviously you seem to have a `@property ... m_selectedItemId` (or at least setter method `setM_selectedItemId`) on SelectedItemViewController, otherwise your code wouldn't even compile. But it seems that `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SelectedItemViewID"]` doesn't really return the expected `SelectedItemViewController`. Hence I have the feeling that you forgot to set the correct class name to `SelectedItemViewController` in your storyboard.

Comment: plu code compiles perfectly, and crash happens when I'm trying to redirect to the new view, property also exists, but I don't have setM_selectedItemId, and looks like it's not mandatory to have that method, as far as I was able to understand from other posts in stackoverflow.

Comment: Check out Wain's answer, I think he's right :). So in Code it would look like:
UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SelectedItemViewID"];
SelectedItemViewController *nextView = (SelectedItemViewController *)navigationController.rootViewController;
nextView.m_selectedItemId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:777];